# How to make the Angular compiler wait the subscription before return

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, subscribe

I have a function has to return a value and inside it I have a subscription, my problem is the return line is being executed before the subscription end,

```
testFunc(){
let objectType;
          let moduleId;
          objectType = valueAsString.split('|');
          objectType = objectType[0];
          this.layoutService.moduleIdByType(objectType)
            .toPromise().then(data => {
              moduleId = data;
            });
          return { IsById: true, LinkedModule: moduleId };
}
```

here I have (moduleIdbytype) and it is changing the value of moduleId variable
and I have to return after the subscription finished and changed the var's value

Comment: If you test it with jasmine, you can take a callback as the first parameter of your test method, then call this callback when your test is finished. Additionally, a default timeout will make the test fail if the callback is not called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your testFunc() async and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the subscription.

```
async testFunc(){
 let objectType;
 let moduleId;
 objectType = valueAsString.split('|');
 objectType = objectType[0];
 const moduleId  = await this.layoutService.moduleIdByType(objectType)
 .toPromise();
 return { IsById: true, LinkedModule: moduleId };
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but the return value of the function was confusing, ```__zone_symbol__state: null
__zone_symbol__value: []
Symbol(Symbol.species): (...)
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)
[[Prototype]]: Object ```

Comment: testFunc() is now an asynchronous function you can either use await or Promise->then(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)